# PHP Query Array to Javascript Google Maps Iterator

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, google-maps

PHP Code

```
$sql = "SELECT location FROM data";    
$result=$conn->query($sql);
$data = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[] = $row["location"];
}
```

Javascript

```
function getPoints(){
    return [
        var coordinateArray = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
        for(i-0;i<coordinateArray.length; i++({
            var sep = coordinateArrays.split(',');
            new google.maps.LatLng(sep[0], sep[1]);
        }
 ];
}
```

Sample data in table:

```
location = 12.121212,13.131313 -> No quotes
data = "Hello"
author="Me"
```

Currently it breaks declaring the Array variable in javascript.Something is breaking there. Any help is appreciated

Comment: So the main problem was my return method for the function. Fixing it worked.

Answer (score 0):

seems you have a name mismatch coordinateArray / coordinateArrays and and index problem try

```
 var coordinateArray = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
    for(i=0; i<coordinateArray.length; i++) {
        var sep = coordinateArray[i].split(',');
        new google.maps.LatLng(sep[0], sep[1]);
    }
```

and also problem with parentesis i++( and assignment i-1 instead of i++) and i=1

Comment: Still is breaking. Seems to be a limit issue possibly. If I look in developer tools for chrome, it shows the values in the array up to a certain limit where it then breaks(after 300 or so coordinates). If it has some upper limit, I need to find a different method as this can have upwards of 10s of thousands of coordinates

Comment: I use normally 50.000 polygons then lot of more coordinates without problems .. then i think is not a limit problem...

Comment: There was an other error in the loop i have correct (i=0 instead of i-0) and wrong parentesis.. ;I have update the answer..